# Symfony 4 - Decimal number in a form returns a null variable

Tags: forms, symfony, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to create a form to publish expense reports in my project.
In the form I set the `totalPrice` field as a `NumberType` with scale 2:

```
      $builder
  ->add('totalPrice', MoneyType::class, array(
      'currency' => '',
      'scale' => 2,
      'label' => false,
      'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Prix'
    )))
```

In my ExpenseReport entity, my totalPrice column is like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=false, name="totalPrice")
 */
private $totalPrice;
```

I tried with `type="decimal", precision=6, precision=2` but it's not working too.

**THE ERROR**

If I dump my `$report` viariable in the Controller, I get this from the form (`totalPrice` is supposed to be 19.99 but now the price is a field of the `$report` array):

```
ExpenseReport {#572 ▼
  -id: null
  -owner: null
  -date: DateTime @1527531970 {#573 ▶}
  -totalPrice: null // WTF ???
  -attachement: UploadedFile {#32 ▶}
  -statut: null
  -refundedPortion: null
  -lastStatutUpdate: null
  -statutUpdateBy: null
  +"19.99": 19.99 // my price is now a field of the array ??
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I edited the post. It is more clear now.

Comment: have you tried with IntegerType::class?

Comment: yes sure. with scale 2.